# How to get all data of a open api site

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to build a movie website. I found a open movie database : http://www.themoviedb.org/ and I need to get all data into my database.

This site provide an api to get data: http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1

So how can I get all data of this database and insert into my database? Should I do it?

Thanks! I'm using php&mysql.

Comment: It looks fairly likely that this would be a violation of their TOS, although what's "unreasonable" is, of course, subjective.

Comment: I think downloading to your own database would be a definite breach of "Thou Shalt Not iii"

Comment: Ok, I think copy their db is not really good. I'll do as jnpcl's solution. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than copying their **entire** database (and having to keep it updated, etc.), what about doing this:

- When a query is made, check if it exists within your database.
- If the entry doesn't exist, query the TMDb API.
- Store the data in your database for future use.

This will help keep your database small, and tuned to your traffic.. and it will ensure that you always have the newest data available from TMDb.

**Update:** there's even an [API call](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/methods/Movie.getVersion) that checks the last updated date of the information. You could store this date in your Database, and use that to verify if your data is still valid.

Comment: Thank! I'm just confusing with the how. But your solution is the best!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the best place to ask would be: http://forums.themoviedb.org/forum/8/api-chat/